# OpenCV phase correlation differs from SciKit

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn

I'm trying to port some code that was originally written in scikit to OpenCV, as I already use OpenCV for some other tasks. I have these two images:

[image: polar-part.png]
[image: polar-template.png]

which are essentially the polar forms of two images that share a common center, where one image is a rotation of the other. I need to use phase correlation to determine what this angle is. In OpenCV, I'm doing:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im1 = np.float32(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('polar-part.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
im2 = np.float32(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('polar-template.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
print(cv2.phaseCorrelate(im1, im2))
```

Which produces the incorrect answer

```
((-0.07302320870314816, -0.19596856380076133), 0.03418491033860195)
```

In Scikit, I do

```
template_polar = rgb2gray(imread('polar-template.png'))
up_cam_polar = rgb2gray(imread('polar-part.png'))

print(phase_cross_correlation(up_cam_polar, template_polar, upsample_factor=20))
```

which produces the correct answer of

```
(array([ 1.3625e+02, -5.0000e-02]), 0.2080647049014251, 2.6434620698588315e-07)
```

The import number here is the y shift, which is about 136. This is the correct number of pixels to translate one image onto the other.

Why does OpenCV give back a drastically different answer?

Comment: Check the documentation for the two with regard to normalization. I suspect they are normalized differently.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell is as follows from the documentation.

Skimage is returning the correct offsets for your images:

```
Returns the (y,x) shifts and the normalized rms error.
```

OpenCV is returning incorrect offsets for your images (phase correlation can be very sensitive to noise and non-cyclic images). Your only available argument would be to adjust the windowing:

```
Returns the (x,y) shifts and the sum of the elements of the correlation (r) within the 5x5 centroid around the peak location. It is normalized to a maximum of 1
```

Here is a different example:

Input 1:

[image]

Input 2:

[image]

Results:

```
opencv: ((20.20846249610655, 22.459076722413144), 0.5959940360504904)

skimage: (array([-22., -20.]), 0.31940809429051836, -2.0134398e-10)
```

which shows equivalent shifts. (The signs are opposite depending upon how the two methods assign the reference and target images). The correlation metric values returned are different, due to the different ways that they are computed and normalized.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You say "phase correlation can be very sensitive to noise", but I thought it was actually very robust to noise. Edge artefacts I could understand being a problem though. I'll try increasing the ROI of my images, or maybe mirroring them at the borders.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation Limitations section and subpixel methods. Subpixel is sensitive to noise. Limitations have to do more with linear shift vs circular shift. Windowing is used to reduce the shift issues. But you can do either too much or too little windowing. OpenCV has an option to modify their default windowing.